# Что за член предложения оборот с "касательно"?

Tags: синтаксис, определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что в предложении "У меня есть пара вопросов касательно вашего отпуска" "касательно вашего отпуска" - это несогласованное определение? Почему-то стал сомневаться. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: «Касательно» в этом предложении — предлог. Я не помню, входят ли предлоги в дополнение или обстоятельство времени. Вроде бы, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*У меня есть пара вопросов  **касательно вашего отпуска**.*

**КАСАТЕЛЬНО,** предлог. кого-чего. Книжн. и офиц. Относительно кого-, чего-л. Быть осведомлённым к. всех обстоятельств дела.

Сравнить: *У меня есть пара вопросов  **о вашем отпуске**.*

1. Согласно учебнику Кустовой (стр. 77 – 81) к существительному могут относиться все **три вида второстепенных членов** (определение, дополнение и обстоятельство), но по вопросу это или **дополнение** (вопрос о чем?), или **определение** (вопрос какой?).
2. Из учебника:  «Косвенное дополнение выражается формами косвенных падежей без предлогов и с предлогами. Дополнение может относиться к глаголу, к существительному, к прилагательному, наречию и др.

Поскольку несогласованные определения при существительных также могут выражаться формами косвенных падежей, возникает проблема их **разграничения** с дополнениями.

Дополнениями считаются такие падежные и предложно-падежные формы, которые соответствуют **объекту** в соотносительных конструкциях с глаголами, например: *мечты (мысли) о будущем – мечтать (думать) о будущем (в некоторых пособиях такие члены предложения называются определительными дополнениями или объектными определениями)».

3. Итак, в общем случае мы имеем **совмещение значений**, но в конкретной ситуации желательно остановиться на том варианте, который  в большей степени соответствует  контексту.

Например: (1) **Какой** вопрос мы еще не обсудили?  – Вопрос касательно отпуска. (2)  **О чем** вы с вами сейчас говорили?  Ах да,  обсуждали вопрос касательно отпуска.

4. Вывод: У меня есть пара вопросов  (о чем? каких?) ***касательно вашего отпуска***.

Это **определительное дополнение**.  Но и объектным определением его тоже можно назвать.

[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)